# Invalid or Unqualified Reference When Using With Block

Tags: vba, excel

Relevant code is below. Essentially I set Worksheet to a sheet within my workbook. Within a with block I call the BuildProgressionArrays function. I get an Invalid or Unqualified Reference error when I attempt to set searchRange. If I add another Set Worksheet and With block the function works fine. Why does it lose the set worksheet when I call a function?

```
Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("progression")
    totalResourcesStored = 1200
    With Worksheet
        For i = 1 To 10
            thisLevelTotalBuilt = 0
            ***BuildProgressionArrays (i)***
            Call BuildGenStoreAndPuzzleArrays
            thisLevelGen = GenRateArray(i - 1)
            thisLevelStorage = StorageAmountArray(i - 1)
            thisLevelPuzzleReward = PuzzleRewardArray(i - 1)
            thisLevelTotalToBuild = Application.Sum(ProgressionBuildNumArray)
            Do While thisLevelTotalBuilt < thisLevelTotalToBuild
                For k = LBound(ProgressionKeyArray) To UBound(ProgressionKeyArray)
                Next k
            Loop
        Next i
    End With



  Function BuildProgressionArrays(townHallLevel As Integer)
    ReDim ProgressionKeyArray(0)
    ReDim ProgressionBuildCostArray(0)
    ReDim ProgressionBuildTimeArray(0)
    ReDim ProgressionBuildNumArray(0)
    n = 0
    Set searchRange = .range("C9:C500")
```

Comment: `With` blocks do not extend to sub-routines called from within the block.  An appropriate solution would be to pass the sheet object as a parameter to `BuildProgressionArrays`   And if `BuildProgressionArrays` doesn't return any value it would be better as a sub, not a Function.

Comment: If you don't mind expounding a little bit. Why is it better as a sub if it doesn't return any value?

Comment: A Sub and a Function are both methods, but it's typical practice to use a Function when a method returns a value, and a Sub when it doesn't.  It is not "wrong" to do the opposite, but is slightly confusing to other people who may end up reading your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is outside of the scope of your sub.  You would need to pass it the worksheet as an object.

Check out http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx

Try changing your function code to the below.

```
Function BuildProgressionArrays(townHallLevel As Integer,WS as WorkSheet)
ReDim ProgressionKeyArray(0)
ReDim ProgressionBuildCostArray(0)
ReDim ProgressionBuildTimeArray(0)
ReDim ProgressionBuildNumArray(0)
n = 0
Set searchRange = ws.range("C9:C500")
```

and then calling it as below.

```
BuildProgressionArrays (i,Worksheet)
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. I assumed passing the worksheet would still require a with block, pleasantly surprised.